# Using scipy.optimize.minimize to fit the sum of functions to allow individual decomposition

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have some x, y and y_error data

The ranges and for my data are roughly on orders of

- x data: [0,40]
- y data: [10^-14, 10^-12]
- y_error data: [10^-15, 10^-14]

Plotting this yields the following graph:

[image: plot of data]

I am now trying to fit a function(s) to this data.

Based on some (irrelevant to this question) background information, I am assuming that the data is best described by the sum of two functions. Which I want to fit (the sum of both) and then, using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to return the free parameters in the total function, I wish to then plot the individual functions by inputting the constrained free parameters into them.

The (total) function I am trying to fit takes the form

y = y_e * exp(-b((x/x_e)^(1/n) -1) + yO * exp(-x / h)

where b is just some constant * n and the free parameters that I wish to constrain are: y_e, x_e, n, yO and h.

After constraining these, I can plot both functions separately by substituting the free params into each function.

To do this, I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to maximise the negative likelihood function (which I am under the impression is the best way to approach this problem but if anyone has any other insights I am open to suggestions!)

My code is as follows, first my log likelihood function:

```py
    def se_log_likelihood(params, x, y, y_error):
    
        y_e, xe, n, yO, h = params #free parameters which we want to constrain
    
        b = 1.9992*n - 0.3271
    
        model = yO * np.exp(-x / h) + y_e * np.exp(-b * ((x/x_e)**(1/n) - 1))
    
        sigma2 = y_error**2 #variance
    
        #log_likelihood function 
    
        log_likelihood = -0.5 * np.sum((I - model)**2 / sigma2 + np.log(2 * np.pi * sigma2))
    
        return log_likelihood
```

Then, the negative log likelihood

```py
    nll_se = lambda *args: - se_log_likelihood(*args) #NLL function
```

Next, minimizing the function

```py
    initial = np.array([5*10**-10, 10, 10, 5*10**-12,12]) #initial estimates for our parameters, 


    soln = minimize(nll_se, initial,args=(x_data ,y_data,y_error_data))
```

However, when I look at the returned values of the free parameters I am trying to constrain in the `soln.x` array, they are exactly the same as the initial constraints.

The message received is as follows (note, nit = 0), along with the plot produced:

```py
Optimised parameters: 
I0 = 5e-12
h = 12.0
Ie = 5e-10
re = 10.0
n = 10.0
full solution   message: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
  success: False
   status: 2
      fun: 75906.2533828226
        x: [ 5.000e-10  1.000e+01  1.000e+01  5.000e-12  1.200e+01]
      nit: 0
      jac: [-1.423e+10 -1.104e+00  1.385e+01  2.483e+21 -9.133e+03]
 hess_inv: [[1 0 ... 0 0]
            [0 1 ... 0 0]
            ...
            [0 0 ... 1 0]
            [0 0 ... 0 1]]
     nfev: 204
     njev: 32
```

[image: plot produced]

i.e. the solver fails. Just doing some googling, some suggested to change the method used to 'Nelder-mead' in my minimise function.

Doing so changes the success of the solver to `True` with the message

```
Optimised parameters: 
I0 = 5.621727474995023e-12
h = 12.956218130275984
Ie = 7.582365424198714e-21
re = 2.7556515677652014
n = 10.0
full solution        message: Optimization terminated successfully.
       success: True
        status: 0
           fun: 2808.1545374167276
             x: [ 7.582e-21  2.756e+00  1.000e+01  5.622e-12  1.296e+01]
           nit: 340
          nfev: 589
 final_simplex: (array([[ 7.582e-21,  2.756e+00, ...,  5.622e-12,
                         1.296e+01],
                       [ 7.587e-21,  2.756e+00, ...,  5.622e-12,
                         1.296e+01],
                       ...,
                       [ 7.453e-21,  2.756e+00, ...,  5.622e-12,
                         1.296e+01],
                       [ 7.491e-21,  2.756e+00, ...,  5.622e-12,
                         1.296e+01]]), array([ 2.808e+03,  2.808e+03,  2.808e+03,  2.808e+03,
                        2.808e+03,  2.808e+03]))
```

However, the plot produced is as follows:

[image]

When the plot I expect and am trying to get is something like

[image]

where the thick black line is the combined model I have fit and the dashed lines are the separate models that are fit after extracting free parameter values from the total model minimisation.

I do not understand enough about the scipy `minimize` solver yet to know how to go about fixing this or what the issue is - whether it is an issue with the scale of my data perhaps? i.e. small values and an exponential function maybe? But if anyone has any ideas or can give some advice I would appreciate it.

Comment: In the expected plot, how did you generate those lines?

Comment: This cannot be fully answered without data, but I suggest that you do a two-step fit. First, do an `lstsq` on the right-hand tail for a line of best fit, then use those parameters in your estimate for the minimize call.

Comment: I generate the lines by taking the values of the free parameters constrained by my fit and plugging them into the model equation of the lines, which have been defined in my function above. As for data, I am unable to share it but I have given the ranges the data points lie. Least squares won't suffice for a fit like this but I appreciate your help

Comment: Could provide a link to the dataset?

Comment: Your y values are very small. I recommend rescaling them for the fit so they aren't near zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets create a synthetic dataset to replace the missing dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def func1(x, n, xe, ye):
    b = 1.9992 * n - 0.3271
    return ye * np.exp(-b * np.power(x / xe, 1. / n) - 1.)

def func2(x, y0, h):
    return y0 * np.exp(-x / h)

def model(x, n, xe, ye, y0, h):
    return func1(x, n, xe, ye) + func2(x, y0, h)

scale = 1e-11
p = (4.2, 11.2, 56 * scale, 0.52 * scale, 12.1)

np.random.seed(12345)
xexp = np.logspace(-2, np.log10(40), 50, base=10)
sigma = 1e-13
sexp = np.full(xexp.shape, sigma)
noise = sexp * np.random.normal(size=xexp.size)
yth = model(xexp, *p) 
yexp = yth + noise
```

Then we create the associated loss function and we scale data to ensure proper convergence of parameters:

```
def loss_factory(x, y, s):
    def wrapped(p):
        return 0.5 * np.sum(
            np.power((y - model(x, *p)) / s, 2.)
        )
    return wrapped

loss = loss_factory(xexp, yexp / scale, sexp / scale)
```

Now we can minimize the loss function with the help of boundaries:

```
sol = optimize.minimize(
    loss,
    x0=(10, 10, 50, 1, 10),
    bounds=[
        (1e+0, 2e1),
        (1e-1, 2e1),
        (1e-1, 1e2),
        (1e-1, 2e1),
        (1e-1, 2e1),
    ],
)

#       fun: 26.234799581905154
#  hess_inv: <5x5 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
#       jac: array([ 0.01446452, -0.00025722, -0.0002693 ,  0.035147  ,  0.00058797])
#   message: 'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
#      nfev: 606
#       nit: 62
#      njev: 101
#    status: 0
#   success: True
#         x: array([ 4.23351444, 12.04435958, 56.49516374,  0.51168294, 11.79830589])
```

Which seems to be a fair fit, we can estimate model and sub functions:

```
xlin = np.logspace(np.log10(xexp.min()), np.log10(xexp.max()), 200, base=10)
yhat = model(xlin, *sol.x) * scale
f1hat = func1(xlin, *sol.x[:3]) * scale
f2hat = func2(xlin, *sol.x[3:]) * scale

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(xexp, yexp, marker='.')
axe.loglog(xlin, yhat)
axe.plot(xlin, f1hat, "--")
axe.plot(xlin, f2hat, "--")
axe.grid()
```

For this setup of parameters we can clearly see the behaviour you were expecting:

[image]

Now if you drastically increase the `n` parameter the orange curve will drop down intensely. The fit is still fair, but the orange curve is flat and several decades smaller than the green curve:

```
p = (10., 11.2, 56 * scale, 0.52 * scale, 12.1)

#       fun: 27.20550074340622
#  hess_inv: <5x5 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
#       jac: array([-0.00020606, -0.00121076,  0.00017231, -0.00311182,  0.00013891])
#   message: 'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
#      nfev: 198
#       nit: 29
#      njev: 33
#    status: 0
#   success: True
#         x: array([ 9.49277836, 10.25974447, 50.04749403,  0.52249643, 11.48385346])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to look at and help me understand how to go about solving this - I will have a go at rescaling my code to if the results improve